# sorting network for binary values

Tags: sorting, sorting-network

I'm looking for the most efficient sorting network for binary values. In my case, efficiency is the number of compare-and-swap operations required.

Background: [Sorting networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_network) sort a list of values using a sequence of compare-and-swap operations with rigid positions. Due to the rigid sequence, they are suitable for implementation in hardware or for parallelization. I have two sub-questions:

1. If I know that my data is binary, e.g. `(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1 ...)`, can I construct a more efficient sorting network than for arbitrary values?
2. It is trivial to turn algorithms like bubble sort into a sorting network, since the algorithm is using a rigid sequence of compare-and-swap operations. Is there a systematic way to turn *any* sorting algorithm (e.g. [this one for sorting a binary array](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sort-binary-array-using-one-traversal)) into a sorting network? The example algorithm uses compare-and-swap at *dynamic* positions (determined by two shifting indices).

(I should add that one property of sorting networks, namely that multiple compare-and-swap operations can be grouped and performed in parallel (as their index pairs are not overlapping), is not important for my application. I'm just interested in finding the shortest rigid sequence of compare-and-swap operations.)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you need n-1 compares minimal and N-1 swaps maximal. Now find an algorithm for that.

Comment: @wildplasser: What's denoted by lower-case n and uppercase N?

Comment: Sloppyness. Both are assumed to be the size of your array.

Comment: I wonder whether the zero-one principle described at http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~csli/graduate/algorithms/book6/chap28.htm doesn't implicitly prevent the construction of simpler networks for sorting of binary values. *"The zero-one principle says that if a sorting network works correctly when each input is drawn from the set {0,1}, then it works correctly on arbitrary input numbers."* So if I could construct a simpler sorting network for binary numbers than one for arbitrary numbers, it would also work for arbitrary numbers which leads to a contradiction. Or is this interpretation wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sorting network for binary numbers cannot be simpler than one for arbitrary numbers, else there would indeed be a contradiction. So if a network has optimal size (known for up to 12 inputs nowadays) then the same applies for binary inputs.

"Sorting" binary numbers is in itself of course no meaningful activity: you can just count the 1's in the input vector and directly produce the output from it.

Comment: I think the latter is true if only the binary keys are sorted, but not if a payload (like an index) is moved together with the key.

Comment: @Ralf move the keys with `0` to the position of `Zero_counter++`, and the keys with `1` to the position of `One_counter++`.